# How do I setup a relation table in firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, xamarin.forms

I am learning Firebase and am using it within a Xamrain forms setting. Say for example I have a list of students, and those list of students have a workout attached each to them.

My Main question is how does one set up a relation table I presume I am doing the right thing when I creating my students by using the guid.newguid from c# so that I have some way to filter out the workouts based on that student.

Also, how does one create the table without data in it when we eventually ship it to the client. For example in SQL I could have empty tables ready for the client to use their app can I still have that with firebase.

```
public async Task AddStudent(Guid studentId, string name)
{
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        await firebase
          .Child("Students")
          .PostAsync(new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName ="Matt",LastName="Smith",DOB=date.AddDays(-43) });

        await firebase
          .Child("Students")
          .PostAsync(new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "Martha", LastName = "Jones",DOB=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-36) });
}
```

My Student Class

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }     
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }

}

public class Workout
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentId{ get; set; } 
    public decimal PB { get; set; } 
    public decimal PU { get; set; } 
 }
```

I would want to list the workouts against each student, I am having a hard time understanding that firebase and other databases don't like relationship data. Having come from a SQL background for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say for example I have a list of students, and those list of students have a workout attached each to them.

Both databases, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) can help you achieve what you want. But since you have used the [firebase-realtime-database](/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database) tag, I'll show you a database structure in which you can create a relationship between students and workouts.

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- students
  |    |
  |    --- $studentId
  |           |
  |           --- //student details
  |
  --- workouts
       |
       --- $studentId
              |
              --- //workout details
```

So as you can see, there is no need for any denormalization (duplicating data). To get the workouts that correspond to a specific student, you should create a reference that points to the `workouts/$studentId` node. You can also nest the workouts under each specific student but this means that every time you download a student data, you download it together with all workouts. So it's up to you to decide which solution is better for your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are no tables in NoSQL databases, so these relationships with junction tables do not exist. When working with a NoSQL database (any NoSQL, not just RTDB or Firestore), the structure and methodology is completely different than the SQL structure you're used to, so you'll have to learn to stop thinking in terms of SQL. Instead of highly structured tables, NoSQL databases generally contain loosely structured documents (RTDB is a little different).

The way to keep track of relationships in a NoSQL database, is to actually *duplicate* pieces of that data. For example, you have a list of workouts and users. Each workout is associated with multiple users. What you would do is create a reference to each user (eg. an array of user ids) on each workout.

Since you come from a SQL background, it may be worth your time to look into using Firestore instead of RTDB. Firestore is more structured (uses collections and documents instead of RTDBs giant JSON tree), and allows for more complex queries, which may be easier for you to work with. There are other differences between the databases as well, so take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) to choose the one that's best for your project

Answer (score 0):

The databases available in Firebase, including the Realtime Database which I assume you are implementing are NoSQL. A relationship between a Student and a Workout can be implemented in a different way than a relationship between two entities in SQL. According to the [structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) of a JSON tree, you can create both Student and Workout structures in the following way:

```
{
    "students": {
        "st1": {
            "name": "john",
            "age": 24,
            "workoutroutine": "wk1"
        },
        ...
    },

    "workouts": {
        "wk1": {
            "name": "track",
            "durationhours": 3 
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

In this simple example (however it depends on the scenario) each student can be mapped to a specific workout, creating a relationship between a student and a workout. Since the Realtime database is a JSON tree, you can implement logic in your application to fetch any type of field from the structure (like students that have “wk1” as their workout routine). [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) is more information about querying data from the Realtime Database